# TypeScript not finding definitions

Tags: typescript, definition, ambient

I have the following file structure:

```
+ src
|  test.ts
|  z_module.d.ts
tsconfig.json
```

`test.ts`

```
// does nothing?
/// <reference path="./z_module.d.ts" />
// can't now write:
var a: zzrm.zzrmObject;

// have to use:    
import * as zzrm from 'zzrm';
var a: zzrm.zzrmObject;
```

`z_module.d.ts`

```
declare module "zzrm" {
  export interface zzrmObject {id: string}
}
```

I have tried to reduce the problem but may well have reduced it incorrectly.  The problem originally came from trying to use sequelize-auto-ts.  [Downloading the repo](https://github.com/samuelneff/sequelize-auto-ts), **upgrading the sequelize.d.ts** and opening in Visual Studio Code (version 0.10.6) immediately highlights [this line](https://github.com/samuelneff/sequelize-auto-ts/blob/master/lib/sequelize-models.ts#L16) with the error "Cannot find namespace 'sequelize'."

```
var Sequelize:sequelize.SequelizeStatic = require('sequelize');
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

Even though [sequelize.d.ts](https://github.com/samuelneff/sequelize-auto-ts/blob/master/lib/sequelize.d.ts) is successfully reference at the top of the file with: `/// <reference path="../../typings/sequelize/sequelize.d.ts" />`

Answer (score 0):

The above "reduced" example works if the zzrm module is declared without the quotation marks:

```
declare module zzrm {
  export interface zzrmObject {id: string}
}
```

When I updated the sequelize.d.ts I failed to note that the module declaration had changed from

```
declare module sequelize { ... }
```

to

```
declare module "sequelize" { ... }
```

This is referred to in the TypeScript docs under ["Ambient External Modules"](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries) but I haven't quite yet figured out how these parts all fit together and why they require you to also add `import * as zzrm from 'z_module'`;